# R Shiny filter on data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I need to apply a filter on data frame in my Shiny App.
I am looking for some button (small one) that opens a multiselect list of values of a specific column. Something like Excel's table filter

[image: Excel pivot table filter]

As an example (from [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646249/r-shiny-select-variable-based-on-checkboxgroupinput?rq=1)):

```
library(shiny)
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("specy", "Specy", choices = levels(iris$Species)),
    tableOutput("content")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$content <- renderTable({
      iris[iris$Species == input$specy, ]
    })
  }
))
```

Some idea from [the widget fallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html): use `checkboxGroupInput` that appears clicking on `actionButton`

All kind of suggestions are welcome. Thank's

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you looking for a way to have the checkbox only show up when the button is clicked?

Comment: Exactly! And hidden after apply a filter

Answer (score 3):

This gets you most of the way, but it doesn't have a way to hide the checkbox once you have selected an option:

```
library(shiny)
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("show_checkbox", "Show Choices"),
    uiOutput("checkbox"),
    tableOutput("content")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$checkbox <- renderUI({
        if ( is.null(input$show_checkbox) ) { return(NULL) }
        if ( input$show_checkbox == 0 ) { return(NULL) }
        return(checkboxGroupInput("specy", "Specy", choices = levels(iris$Species)))
    })
    output$content <- renderTable({
        if ( is.null(input$specy) ) { return(iris) }
        if ( length(input$specy) == 0 ) { return(iris) }
      iris[iris$Species == input$specy, ]
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: thank's for a fast answer. Could we substitute actionButton with something like toggleButton?

Comment: I've found it in ‘shinyBS’: `bsButton(..., type = "toggle")`

Comment: To retract the list with a second click, change the second condition in `output$checkbox` to `input$show_checkbox %% 2 == 0`. However, reopening it will re initialize the filtering.