# Displaying multiple checkboxes given colnames within R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to take colnames from a table and then each of these to produce however many checkboxes I need. However, I continue to get the following error:

> Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Here is my code:

```
lemon<-read.csv("LemonData.csv")
 csvuploaded<-TRUE
 shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         uiOutput(outputId="factorcheckboxes")
         )    
   )), 
   server = function(input, output) {    
     output$factorcheckboxes <- renderUI({
       if(is.null(csvuploaded))
         return(NULL)
       if(!(is.null(csvuploaded)))
         collen<-length(colnames(lemon))
         factornames<-vector()
         for(i in 1:collen){
           factornames<-c(factornames,colnames(lemon)[i])
         }
         checkboxGroupInput(inputId="variable",label="Variable:",choices=as.list(factornames),selected=NULL,inline=FALSE)
     })    
   })
```

I get a similar error when I try to run the sample given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646249/r-shiny-select-variable-based-on-checkboxgroupinput). I cannot pinpoint the source in the code with such an error, and I'm not sure how to use breakpoints when debugging Shiny.

UPDATE:
Requested sample of LemonData.csv:

```
------------------------------------------
Response | Factor 1 | Factor 2 | Factor 3
------------------------------------------
5        | 2        | 5        | 2        
------------------------------------------
7        | 1        | 4        | 3
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of "LemonData.csv"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server function can be made much simpler, you just pass `colnames(lemon)` to the `choices` argument, there is no need for that `for` loop.  Also, you are checking for TRUE/FALSE with `is.null` which is incorrect since both TRUE and FALSE are not NULL.

```
lemon <- read.table(text="Response, Factor 1, Factor 2, Factor 3
5, 2, 5, 2        
7, 1, 4, 3", header=T, sep=",")
csvuploaded<-FALSE

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              radioButtons("csvuploaded", "uploaded", c(T, F)),  # change csvuploaded
              uiOutput(outputId="factorcheckboxes")
            ),
            mainPanel()
        )), 
    server = function(input, output) {    
        output$factorcheckboxes <- renderUI({
            if(input$csvuploaded) {
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId="variable",
                                   label="Variable:",
                                   choices=colnames(lemon), selected=NULL, inline=FALSE)
            } else { NULL }
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: So I can run this script by typing it directly into the R Terminal, but is there a reason why I cannot paste it into a .R file and hit "Run App" without the error "Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector" reappearing.

Comment: Are you talking about pasting this code into an .R file or your code?  What application are you using to hit "Run App"?

Comment: Pasting the following into a blank .R file and I am using RStudio.

Comment: it sounds like there is something wrong with the way your files are laid out.  Try creating a new shiny project, deleting ui.R and server.R, then creating a file app.R with the above code pasted in it.  That should run fine when you click Run App in RStudio (I just tested it).  I'm not all that familiar with RStudio though, I use emacs.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I guess it gets confused when there are multiple R files within the same directory.

Comment: @engineerchange yea, it must check for ui and server first, and only if they don't exists it checks for app.R.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the error, but I was able to generate the checkboxes with the code below. The only problem was the `mainPanel` argument missing, since you are using the `sidebarLayout`.

```
lemon<-read.csv("LemonData.csv")
csvuploaded<-TRUE
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput(outputId="factorcheckboxes")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        )
    )), 
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$factorcheckboxes <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(csvuploaded))
        return(NULL)
      if(!(is.null(csvuploaded)))
        collen<-length(colnames(lemon))
      factornames<-vector()
      for(i in 1:collen){
        factornames<-c(factornames,colnames(lemon)[i])
      }
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId="variable",label="Variable:",choices=as.list(factornames),selected=NULL,inline=FALSE)
    })    
  })
```

I generated a "LemonData.csv" according to the table provided, which looks like:

```
Response, Factor 1, Factor 2, Factor 3
5, 2, 5, 2        
7, 1, 4, 3
```